# How can I ensure that only data entered gets inserted into the db?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hello again and please forgive me for posting again. I do this when I realize I am having problem fixing it myself.

Please take a look at the code below. I was told by the individual that developed it originally that the code only adds the rows of data the user entered. In other words, there 5 rows of textboxes. A user can enter data into one row or into all 5 rows. If the user enters data into one row of textbox, that's what gets inserted into the db.

I made some minor change to the code so that users can tell when a payment is made by check or cash payment.

Since I made that change, whether a user enters data into one row or all 5 rows, all 5 rows get inserted into the db.

How can I modify this code to ensure only rows entered get inserted?

I am really,really sorry for bothering you guys again and many thanks for all your help.

```
    For x = 1 To 5 Step 1
        dedval = obr.FindControl("ded" & CStr(x))
        chckvalflag = obr.FindControl("chck" & CStr(x))
        checkboxval = obr.FindControl("chckBox" & CStr(x))
        onetimeval = obr.FindControl("onetime" & CStr(x))
        chcknumval = obr.FindControl("chcknum" & CStr(x))
        multival = obr.FindControl("multi" & CStr(x))
        *If (chckvalflag.Text <> "" Or chckvalflag.Text <> "0") And Not checkboxval.Checked Then
            cashval = DirectCast(obr.FindControl("chck" & CStr(x)), TextBox).Text
            chckval = ""
            chcknumval.Text = "Cash Payment"
        Else
            chckval = DirectCast(obr.FindControl("chck" & CStr(x)), TextBox).Text
            chcknumval = obr.FindControl("chcknum" & CStr(x))
        End If*
        If dedval.Text <> "-1" And donatechoice.SelectedItem.Value <> "No" Then
            sql += "INSERT INTO Contribs (employee_id, charity_code, check_amt, chcknum, one_time, bi_weekly, cash, donate_choice, date_stamp) "
            sql += "VALUES ('" & Replace(employee_idLabel.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(dedval.SelectedValue, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(chckval, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(chcknumval.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(onetimeval.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & multival.Text & "','" & Replace(cashval, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(donatechoice.SelectedItem.Value, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(datestamp, "'", "''") & "');"
        End If
        If donatechoice.SelectedItem.Value = "No" Then
            x = 6
            sql += "INSERT INTO Contribs (employee_id, charity_code, check_amt, chcknum, one_time, bi_weekly, cash, donate_choice, date_stamp) "
            sql += "VALUES ('" & Replace(employee_idLabel.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(dedval.SelectedValue, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(chckval, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(chcknumval.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(onetimeval.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(multival.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(cashval, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(donatechoice.SelectedItem.Value, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(datestamp, "'", "''") & "');"
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: You don't have to apologize for posting questions. It keeps us entertained, and it's the lifeblood of this site.

Comment: Thank you very much James. I really appreciate that. BTW: My cousin's name is James Johnson and he is a priest. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add some conditions to validate the data was entered into the inputs in each row.

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(String.Concat(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text)) Then
    'insert logic here
End If
```

On a side note, I would suggest modifying the code to use parameters instead. The code is ripe for SQL-injection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look into using parametrized [stored procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) instead of building your SQL as a string.  Right now your application can be [SQL injected](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection&rct=j&q=sql%20injection&ei=B9SNTvymI6_FsQLnlYGoAQ&usg=AFQjCNGcGZNbIk2jM8itxItHrCja7eJ0PQ&sig2=dNCxhz8EpX6uuTZpR-qGjA&cad=rja).  If you gave me a link to your application, I could wipe out all the data in your `Contribs` table (assuming the identity the thread is running under has permission; regardless, your query can be killed via syntax based on user input).
2. If you only want to insert records depending on what textboxes the user filled out, just use a case statement or if block to check for values in those textboxes.  If the user entered a value, execute a function which hits the database.